# Show Password icon in TextInputLayout touching the base line

Tags: android, material-design

I had some problem with my show password icon in TextInputLayout with `android:inputType="textPassword"`. Right now it is showing like this [image]

As you can see the show password icon is touching the base line.
I want something like this[image]

You can see the gap between them.

The xml sode for implementing TextInputLayout is given below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/TextLabelSNA"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mailSave"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/tilOp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Old Password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#0A0B12"
        android:id="@+id/oldPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

style used is:

```
<style name="TextLabelSNA" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hintBlack</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/hintBlack</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/hintBlack</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/hintBlack</item>
</style>
```

Please Help..!!!

Comment: did you try increasing the font size?

Comment: @JoxTraex changing font size to 20sp works. But I have some constraints I can't increase size more than 16sp.
Any other solution?

Comment: Is there any to add a text instead of an icon ?

Answer (score 74):

just add app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" in your textinputlayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            app:layout_widthPercent="90%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@android:color/white">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:visibility="gone"
                 />


        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Waav..Super answer brother

Comment: this shoud be accepted! it works (at least for me) :)

Comment: Since AndroidX "refactor", package of classes to use is "com.google.android.material.textfield." instead of "android.support.design.widget."

Comment: app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" attribute is deprecated. In that place should use this app:endIconMode="password_toggle".

Answer (score 6):

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtpwd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="  Password"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp">

        </EditText>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your support library version:`24.2.0` library have bug if yes 
then make it version:`24.2.1`

[image]

Use this code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:text="a1234"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Icon is cutting just because of your padding and margine section.

Comment: Added Actual View what in my layout.Please check updated answer

Comment: Activity theme may differ in your case use Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar as parent theme

Comment: Please also check support lib version

Comment: It's already 24.2. 1 Actually it's a bug which is already reported.

Comment: Since AndroidX "refactor", package of classes to use is "com.google.android.material.textfield." instead of "android.support.design.widget."

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly a bug noticed by others as well and reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222307&q=textinputlayout&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Actually, I think I narrowed it down to the text size. The default text size in an edittext is 18sp. With that text size I think it looks well. If I set the text size to 15sp, then that happens. In hindsight I don't think it's a bug, it's just that the drawable doesn't have enough room. If that's still happening even though you didn't set the text size yourself, then I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove error icon - (JUST IN CASE)
You can add this line in TextInputLayout.

```
app:errorIconDrawable="@null"
```

Answer (score -5):

Add a library dependency in your gradle

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.8'
}
```

then add remote maven url

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}`
```

lastly add this in your xml.It's just like the regular EditText

```
 <com.scottyab.showhidepasswordedittext.ShowHidePasswordEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/simplePassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        />
```

For details, go through this link
[Show/Hide Password EditText](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2881)

Comment: Since it's now included in support library, there's no need to use this library. In fact, it's deprecated. See this article: https://medium.com/@moyinoluwa/password-visibility-toggle-android-support-library-revision-24-2-0-98b422087e5a

Comment: This solution is deprecated

Comment: This is dpricated now.